# Area of sphere inside a cylinder (and of the cylinder insider the sphere)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

The unit sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and the right circular cylinder $x^2+y^2=y$

Find the area of the portion of the sphere that is inside the cylinder and the area of the portion of the cylinder that is inside the sphere.

I know that we can say $f(x,y)=1-x^2-y^2$. So we should parametrise in terms of $r \space\text{and} \space\theta$. But I don't see how to do it.

Comment: First, write down the area formula. The area of the sphere inside the cylinder works out nicely in polar coordinates.

Comment: And the area of the cylinder inside the sphere?

Comment: Typo? $ RHS = y, ... ; = 1 $